# Incorrect Syntax near Insert expecting '(' , or Select

Tags: sql

[image] I am facing this problem, can someone say why?

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Please show us the code in text in the question, not with a screenshot. Also explain what you expect the statement to do and which DB it is targeting.

Comment: You need a , before  ('1002'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The records to insert into the table should be *comma* separated (and terminated with a semicolon):

```
INSERT INTO ... (...)
VALUES
    (...),
    (...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have used int type for column EmployeeID so you donot need to use quote for it.

Also you need to seperate multiple row entries by comma.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
  ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
VALUES
  ('John', 123, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Jane', 124, 'Lloyds Office'), 
  ('Billy', 125, 'London Office'),
  ('Miranda', 126, 'Bristol Office');
```